# Integrating test results with jira

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I need to integrate my selenium automation results with jira(jmp newer version). In simple i need to get the test results in jira so that everyone in my team can able to view the test results

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried and let us know where you stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead send out the results to their emails at the end of the automation,
because

> JIRA is only for BUG tracking.

After your result, we can automatically create BUGS but **results viewing** is not fit for that.